# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, opencv, object, attributeerror, nonetype

The full error is :

````
    OpenCV: out device of bound (0-0): 1
    OpenCV: camera failed to properly initialize!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/syedrishad/PycharmProjects/OpenCVPython/venv/project1.py", line 60, in <module>
        imgResult = img.copy()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
     ```
````

The full code is :

````
```import cv2
import numpy as np

frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
cap.set(10, 150)

myColors = [[78, 119, 70, 255, 97, 255],
            [63, 108, 44, 255, 0, 118],
            [0, 179, 69, 255, 100, 255],
            [90, 48, 0, 118, 255, 255]]
myColorValues = [[51, 153, 255],  ## BGR
                 [255, 0, 255],
                 [0, 255, 0],
                 [255, 0, 0]]

myPoints = []  ## [x , y , colorId ]


def findColor(img, myColors, myColorValues):
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    count = 0
    newPoints = []
    for color in myColors:
        lower = np.array(color[0:3])
        upper = np.array(color[3:6])
        mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lower, upper)
        x, y = getContours(mask)
        cv2.circle(imgResult, (x, y), 15, myColorValues[count], cv2.FILLED)
        if x != 0 and y != 0:
            newPoints.append([x, y, count])
        count += 1
        # cv2.imshow(str(color[0]),mask)
    return newPoints


def getContours(img):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    x, y, w, h = 0, 0, 0, 0
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 500:
            # cv2.drawContours(imgResult, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
            peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * peri, True)
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    return x + w // 2, y


def drawOnCanvas(myPoints, myColorValues):
    for point in myPoints:
        cv2.circle(imgResult, (point[0], point[1]), 10, myColorValues[point[2]], cv2.FILLED)


while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgResult = img.copy()
    newPoints = findColor(img, myColors, myColorValues)
    if len(newPoints) != 0:
        for newP in newPoints:
            myPoints.append(newP)
    if len(myPoints) != 0:
        drawOnCanvas(myPoints, myColorValues)

    cv2.imshow("Result", imgResult)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break ```
````

How do I fix this error? Any help would be gladly appreciated, I've been trying and failing to find an answer for a week now. I am not able to understand why it isn't working. I've looked at other examples of this error, but none of the solutions work.
Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like the camera isn't being detected. [See the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) "The methods/functions combine VideoCapture::grab() and VideoCapture::retrieve() in one call. ... **If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer.**", or in the case of Python, it will return `None`

Answer (score 5):

The line that causes the error:

```
imgResult = img.copy()
```

Making use of `img` defined in the previous line:

```
success, img = cap.read()
```

The [`read`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) docs state:

> The methods/functions combine VideoCapture::grab() and VideoCapture::retrieve() in one call. This is the most convenient method for reading video files or capturing data from decode and return the just grabbed frame. If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer.

So apparently `img` is `None` due to no data read.

Change to:

```
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if img is None:
        break
    imgResult = img.copy()
```

Plus check what causes that no frames have been grabbed, either:

1. Camera has been disconnected (check all drivers to make sure it is installed and detected)
2. There are no more frames in video file

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use the webcam. Please change the value to 0 as it's for using webcam. Have a nice day.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```